# Successfully added to cart message needs to show on a specific page

Tags: css, popup

I have created my own menu page and have created a redirect function so that it redirects after the person hits the "add to cart" button, to go back to the our menu page so they can continue shopping. I would like the 'You have added this product to the cart' message to show up on this page after the redirect. I know that I need to add in a function that will either show this message on the page or create one that shows on the page but not sure exactly how to do so. Please help!

The page is https://notjustcurries.ca/our-menu/

Comment: Fetch the last line from the order when you are constructing the page and show a message.